# Limiting Characters to a specfic width

Tags: php, font-size

I have run into this problem a few times. I have no problem limiting characters in a string to a specific number. However, some characters are longer than others so it wraps to another line or makes my DIV element wider and not uniform with the rest of my website.

For instance:

```
Literacy - Is it the Sa
Machu Picchu, Cuzco, Pe
```

are the exactly the same amount of characters (23) including spaces but the Machu Pichu one is longer in terms of the actual width on screen.

Is there any way to have a uniform size for a string that is based on the width of the actual string as opposed to the number of characters? Someone has had to have come up with a solution to this before right?

Comment: you could use a monospaced font: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Comment: did you see my js + css solution?

Comment: @andre matos I am taking a look at it now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First (obvious) solution: switch to a fixed-width font such as Courier, Lucida Console, Consolas, etc.
- Second solution: use the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to [write strings to a graphic object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) and measure that object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured there were fixed-width fonts out there. Unfortunately my clients don't like them. I'll have to explore the GD Lib or a javascript solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to play with GD and imagefontwidth(): https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imagefontwidth.php

Comment: Note that this will give you the length of the string based on GD's font-rendering mechanism and might not match up with the actual length on the end user's browser (even if it matches up with yours) -- this is a good way to approximate the width, but it will not give you exact results (exact results can only be obtained from javascript -- because javascript runs on the end user's browser, it has perfect information about it).

Comment: Agree with you, @Ben Lee, it's an approximate method. Just tryin' to keep in the question's scope. With JavaScript I believe you'd need do some math along with the CSS style of the given DIV... would require some thinking, but it's probably possible.

Comment: No JS hacks are needed, and no PHP!, you just have to combine JS and CSS, take a look at my solution and let me know if you can spot any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without writing an algorithm in PHP to limit characters based on "font-widths" for the specific font you are using, you can use a monospace font.

Alternatively, I'm sure a JavaScript solution could be written as well to test the widths, but I'm not sure how off of the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in PHP -- the best you can do is approximate. Different browsers and different operating systems render font widths differently for the same font. So even if you manually stored an array of character font widths for the font on your browser and os, it might not match up with others.

It's usually better to work your design around the possibility of different-width fonts than to try to force it.

That being said, this can be done perfectly (without approximation) in javascript, albeit with a little bit of a hack. There are a number of possible methods, but here's one: Start by rendering the full string in a div that has width that you are looking for, then measure the div's height. If it is larger than one line could possibly be, then start a loop progressively removing the last word. Keep going until the height of the div is for one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for formatting so they all have uniform widths - no jagged edges on the right side. Something like this:

```
p { text-align: justify; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had some fun workin on this CSS + JS solution. It wasn't tested intensively (Firefox + IE7/8) but it should work ok...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
    .monospaced, .not-monospaced{
        font: normal normal 16px/16px Verdana; /* not monospaced font */
        clear: both;
    }
    .monospaced span{
        float: left;
        display: block;
        width: 16px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.monospaced').each(function(){
            var monospace = $(this).html(); // .trim() does not work at IE http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/ (view comments)
            monospace.replace(/(^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$)/g, '');
            mono = monospace.split('');

            for(i = 0; i < mono.length; i++){
                if(mono[i] == ' ')
                    mono[i] = '&nbsp;';

                mono[i] = '<span>'+mono[i]+'</span>';
            }

            $(this).html(mono.join(''));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="not-monospaced">
        This is supposed to be monospaced...
    </div>
    <div class="not-monospaced">
        mmmm mm mmmmmmmm mm mm mmmmmmmmmm...
    </div>

    <div class="monospaced">
        This is supposed to be monospaced...
    </div>
    <div class="monospaced">
        mmmm mm mmmmmmmm mm mm mmmmmmmmmm...
    </div>
</body>
```