# How can I force fixed character width with CSS for ANY glyph, including arcane Unicode?

Tags: css, character, fixed-width

I suspect that this can't be done, but I'm asking just to be sure.

I'd like to force a single character in a `<span>` to have a specific `width` and `height`: `1em`.

Ideally the character would be stretched to 1em if it is not already fixed-width.

This must support **any character**, including rare Unicode glyphs, so I cannot just set the font to Courier.

Finally, this should be accomplished with only CSS, and be simple and lightweight. E.g. a complex solution which includes a `div` within a `table` containing a one-pixel image (just to display this single character) is *not* OK.

I can't remember any property which does this, and attempts to Google have just returned a lot of "fixed width layouts" and nothing about single characters.

If there is no simple solution, but there *is* a complex one, I won't use it, but I'd be curious to hear it anyway.

Comment: This question is similar to another stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258872/limiting-characters-to-a-specfic-width

Comment: @Brian, that question doesn't specify a formatting strategy -- though it is tagged `[php]` -- while this one explicitly requests CSS.

Comment: That's why I didn't vote to close this question as a duplicate. It's a related issue, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @Brian, okay, fair enough. I wouldn't even call them similar enough for the comment, but that's getting really subjective and non-productive.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@font-face` to include a fixed width font with good unicode support. The [DejaVu family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts) has excellent unicode support and a mono variant, and should do this nicely. You can use [FontSquirrel's `@font-face` generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create the files you need for this.

Answer (score 3):

While I like Yi Jiang's answer, I think you might be better served by GNU Unifont based on the short discussion at [this page](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_unicode_fonts.html) and Wikipedia's list of [typefaces with good Unicode support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_fonts). Notably, that first page points out that DejaVu Sans Mono misses some glyphs which, depending on your application, may be fairly common.

Comment: DejaVu Sans Mono currently offers most (maybe all) of the characters that were mentioned as missing in the article you linked to.

Comment: Hm, it's blocked here at work now, but I'll try to check this out later, thanks for the tip.