# Disable Firefox's collapsing of 11 which made it less wide than 01 or 02

Tags: css, firefox, text

In Firefox now, the 1 is not as wide as the zero and other digits. This reduces the nice look of a list of dates. It only seems to be a problem with 11. 01 and 10 seem unaffected.

> 2012-09-30 23:56:54
>   2012-11-14 11:12:56
>   2012-12-30 12:12:56
>   2013-02-05 12:12:56

Notice how the second date/time is not as long when using the Firefox browser. Is there a way I can normalize this again / 'turn off' this new Firefox feature for my web page?

Since this is a minor issue, I am not interested in switching fonts. I would much prefer a simple CSS rule, if there is one.

**Edit** I am specifically referring to the Arial font, and here is a screenshot of what I see. The second row of text has two elevens in it. Thus it is two pixels shorter than the other lines which do not have 11.

[image]

Comment: take a peek at this thread, see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258872/limiting-characters-to-a-specfic-width

Comment: The simple CSS rule you seek involves switching fonts.

Comment: @Jeff, I do not see how that relates. (I already know the difference between fixed width and variable width fonts.)